# Data structure in web development

Tags: data-structures

how the large social networking sites store data such as friend list...is it possible to implement data structures such as tree using xml or any other language

Answer (score -1):

> how the large social networking sites store data such as friend list

There is a huge shift towards schemaless/NoSQL/document-oriented databases these days, that support the scenario you mentioned without losing scalability and perform well under high loads.

You might want to have a look at a few to better understand the concept. You can start with [Mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/), apache couchdb, google BigTable/datastore (through app engine), and many others as per your need.